# Prove if $v \bot B^ s v$, then $v=0$ when $s \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v=A^TM(b-Az)$, where $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $M \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. Prove that if $\langle v, B^s v \rangle =0$ then $v=0$. Here $B = A^T M A$ and $s \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $s=0$ is trivial.
In case $s=1$ we have
$$
 0 = v^TBv = (Av)^TM(Av) ,
$$
which implies $Av=0$ by positive definiteness of $M$. Hence $Av = AA^TM(b-Az)=0$. But $AA^Tx = 0$ if and only if $A^Tx=0$, implying $A^TM(b-Az)=0$, and $v=0$.

Let $s\ge 2$. Assume that the claim is proven up to number $s-1$.

Suppose $s$ is even, $s=2k$. Then $0=v^TB^sv = \|B^kv\|^2$, thus $v^TB^kv=0$, implying $v=0$ by induction assumption.

Suppose $s=2k+1$ is odd. Then $0= v^TB^{2k+1}v = (B^kv)^TA^TMA(B^kv)$.
Then $0=A(B^kv)= AA^TMAB^{k-1}v$, hence $A^TMAB^{k-1}v=0$, which is $B^kv=0$.
This implies $v=0$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot!.